# C# Dependent properties, dependency on correct order of setter execution

Tags: c#, oop, properties, xaf

I wonder how to deal with dependent properties in C#. I have following simplified classes (I'm using [DevExpress XAF](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/application_framework/)):

```
public class Company
{
    public ContactMethods? PreferredContactMethod { get; set; }
    // Missing: Collection of Employees...
}

public class Employee
{
    private Company company;

    public Company Company
    {
        get
        {
            return this.company;
        }
        set
        {
            company = value;
            if (company != null && PreferredContactMethod == null)
            {
                PreferredContactMethod = company.PreferredContactMethod;
            }
        }
    }

    public ContactMethods? PreferredContactMethod { get; set; }
}
```

When assigning a Company to an Employee, I set the Employee.PreferredContactMethod to the PreferredContactMethod of the Company (just for convenience, can be changed later).

---

### Update:

I want to use the Company.PreferredContactMethod just as a default value when initializing new Employees. Every Employee stores its own ContactMethod independently from the Company. Later changes to the Company.PreferredContactMethod shouldn't update the Employee.PreferredContactMethod. It is perfectly legal for the Employee.PreferredContactMethod to be null (e.g. if explicitly set be user).

---

Quite simple code and of course this is just working fine. But I think it violates [Microsoft's Property Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229006%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Do allow properties to be set in any order even if this results in a
>   temporary invalid object state.

`Company = A, PreferredContactMethod = null` gives another result than `PreferredContactMethod = null, Company = A`.

I think I cannot rely on a 'correct' order of the property setters (e.g. if using Automapper/Reflection), How do you deal with such a situation? I think it's not uncommon.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want the Employee's PreferredContactMethod to always match that of the Company's? What should happen if you call the setter on  Employee.PreferredContactMethod, would that affect the value of Company.PreferredContactMethod?
Perhaps you could use a custom getter for the Employee, i.e. Employee.PreferredContactMethod returns Employee.company.PreferredContactMethod?

Comment: I updated my requirements. I hope it is more clear now.
I'm using similar code quite often in my Business Objects

Comment: I think my requirement (initializing a property to a default value just for convenience) is somehow UI-related. Maybe using some UI-Controller code is a better approach? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You want to ensure the invariant that the Employee's has the same PreferredContactMethod as this Company himself, unless he has a specified PreferredContancMethod himself. One way, extending your solution, is to implement this is to update this value like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    private Company company;
    public Company Company
    {
        get { return this.company; }
        set
        {
            this.company = value;
            UpdateCompanyPreferredContactMethod();
        }
    }

    private ContactMethods? preferredContactMethod;
    public ContactMethods? PreferredContactMethod 
    {
        get { return this.preferredContactMethod; }
        set
        {
            this.preferredContactMethod = value;
            UpdateCompanyPreferredContactMethod();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateCompanyPreferredContactMethod()
    {
        if (PreferredContactMethod == null)
        {
            PreferredContactMethod = company != null ?company.PreferredContactMethod : null;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this solution is fragile, as you have to update this value every time you change either. Instead, I would actually do something like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    private ContactMethods? preferredContactMethod;
    public ContactMethods? PreferredContactMethod 
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (this.preferredContactMethod != null)
            {
                return this.preferredContactMethod;
            }
            else if (this.Company != null)
            {
                return this.Company.PreferredContactMethod;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        set { this.preferredContactMethod = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your latter example, but I would like to emphasize that OP should consider his/her design requirements. In particular, when should Employee.PreferredContactMethod correspond to Company.PreferredContactMethod?

Comment: Thank you golergka, nice solution. But I think it does not meet my (updated) requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to use the PreferredContactMethod as default value when initializing a new Employee. If this is the case, you should pass the Company to the constructor of the Employee, and set it then:

```
public Employee(Company company) {
    // Null checks as appropriate
    this.company = company;
    this.PreferredContactMethod = company.PreferredContactMethod;
}
```

If you also want to change the PreferredContactMethod the way you do, and your only concern is violating the design guidelines, then maybe use a method `Employee.SetCompany` to indicate that the operation has side effects in addition to just changing the `Company` property.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use the constructor approach. In the framework I'm using (XAF) no real ViewModels exist. GUIs are automatically created and bound to persistent classes.  
A Employees Listview is generated and also a 'New Employee' action to construct a new empty Employee in a DetailView. In the DetailView editors are created for all public properties (but not for methods, so I cannot easily use a SetCompany() method).  
For the Employee two editors are created: A 'Company' lookup and a 'PreferredContactMethod' lookup.  
I guess there is no nice solution without some kind of ViewModel?!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to assign it just before when saving the Employee object therefore any order gives the same result.

try this;

```
if (IsNewRecord && Company != null && PreferredContactMethod == null)
    PreferredContactMethod = Company.PreferredContactMethod;
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I understand your answer. In XAF/XPO there is a virtual OnSaving() method. Should I override it and add your code?
But if someone set 'PreferredContactMethod' explicitly to null, your code would override it...

Comment: That's right so you need extra controls for that case.